# Database design: fast access under heavy loads for my particular problem

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

Let's define a rather abstract game that outlines my problem.  In this game there are *players*, *flags*, and *teams*.  Let's say that there are 1,000,000 players and 500,000 different *types* of flags.  Each player moves around collecting flags, they can hold as many as 20 flags at a time.  However often the player drops flags and occasionally flags are stolen from players.  The goal for each player is to form the largest team possible, where a player *X*'s *teammate* is defined as anyone who has at least one flag type in common with player *X*.

In my database I will store players and flags types as UUIDs.  I will record as flags are picked up and dropped with datetime entries in the database.  So that my database schema may be as simple as:

```
table: GameState
row1: entryId (key)
row2: player (UUID)
row3: flagType (UUID)
row4: findTime (datetime)
row5: dropTime (datetime)
```

Given a player, *X*, what query do I need to make to find all players that were on *X*'s team at datetime *t*?

If I'm concerned about being fast only when determining who is on *X*'s team *now*, does it significantly help to remove old entries (where flags have been dropped)?  Perhaps I'll put them in an old database so that people can make the less frequent queries about previous teams.

I'm concerned with response speed under heavy load.  So any pointers here would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a UUID (3 × 10^38) will kill your response time because of the IO overhead.  If you would use MS SQL Server int type there are 2,147,483,647 positive values and as many in the negative range.

Indexing will determine the query response time also.  An index by the flag value will yield the quickes results of who has X flag.  Removing the dropped flags will decrease the IO involved with the query.

All players sharing at least on flag key is:

```
Select player from GameState where FlagType IN
(Select FlagType from GameState where Player = 'PlayerValue')
```

To make the above query the quickest possible the table should have a clustered index on the Player.  Create a non clustered index on the FlagType.

Comment: Thanks for the advice concerning the UUID.  However there's one necessary aspect to the query that you didn't include, and it's the part I'm more confused about.  In order to be on a team, the players must hold flags of the same type at the *same time*.  And I still need to do this efficiently! :-|

Comment: Use a history table for droped flags and use the query above.  If dropped flags are in a history table one could remove the 'find time' also to reduce IO.